# Play Store change App Developer Email

Tags: android, google-play

I published an app on playstore few days ago

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rezerv.rezervnow

But Developer email is not updating, I already update it in play console developer page section and Account detail
See here
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnB8k.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated in google documentation **You can change the Email Address but can not remove**:

**Contact details**

1. Sign in to your Play Console.
2. Click All applications All applications.
   Select an app.
3. On the left menu, click Store presence > Store listing.
4. At the bottom of the page, type your contact email address or website. **A contact email address is required to publish or update apps on Google Play.**
5. Your contact email address doesn't have to be the same account you use to sign in to your developer account.
   Save your changes.

[Check Official Google Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en)

Comment: you're always welcome. connect with me on fb and get personal help anytime.

Comment: Hi, one extra detail: if you have any pending issue with the data provided (ex: haven't provided the new needed info about target users), you may not be able to change the email until you add that.

Answer (score 3):

In the new play console (as of December 2020)

1. Sign in to your Play Console.
2. Click All applications All applications. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, click Store presence > **Store settings**.
4. Enter email address in **Store Listing contact details**.